# Can we search for Order ID linked to Payment ID through Square Connect API?

Tags: square-connect

Is there a way using the Square Connect API to take a payment ID sent via webhook and find the associated Order ID?

I find it odd that the Payment object listed in the documentation (https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#datatype-payment) does not have an order_id value or the Orders API does not have a get/order_by_payment_id option (https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#navsection-orders).

Are there plans to implement either of these options?

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to get a `Payment` object's associated order ID with the Connect API.

I have filed a feature request with the API development team.

Comment: Any movement on this feature request?  Reconciling payments and orders is a major pain as the api is currently implemented.